# How to Install PCRE Development Headers on Mac OSX

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, passenger, pcre, ruby-on-rails-2

I just upgraded my MacBook Pro to Mavericks and my local Ruby on Rails development environment isn't running straight off the bat, when I visit `localhost` I see `It works!` and remembered I needed to start Phusion Passenger, so when I run `passenger start` it checks all the prerequisites and fails when it gets to the PCRE Development Headers:

```
 * Checking for PCRE development headers...
    Found: no
```

It tells me to go to http://www.pcre.org/ to download them so I downloaded 8.33 from [here](ftp://ftp.csx.cam.ac.uk/pub/software/programming/pcre/) which went to my `Downloads` folder, so I unzipped it, `cd`'d to the folder and ran:

```
./configure
make
make install
```

Then `cd`'d back to my rails app directory on my Desktop and re-ran `passenger start` but it's still the same. Tried a new Terminal window but that didn't make any difference.

I must have done this before to get my dev environment working but can't seem to solve it this time.

I also tried `brew install pcre` but it says `Warning: pcre-8.33 already installed`.

Comment: brew install pcre : worked for me

Comment: brew install pcre - worked for me too

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Reinstall the OS X Developer Tools. It was broken by the Mavericks upgrade.

Answer (score 20):

Reinstalling OS X Developer Tools did not work for me so I recommend

`brew install pcre`

Also you can do

`brew install passenger`

Which will install all needed requirements if additional missing.