# Why this regex does not work with grep?

Tags: regex, macos, bash, grep

I have a text file this way

```
"an arbitrary string" = "this is the text one"
"other arbitrary string" = "second text"
"a third arbitrary string" = "the text number three"
```

I want to obtain only this

```
an arbitrary string
other arbitrary string
a third arbitrary string
```

That is, the text inside the first quotes, or between the first `"` and the `" =`. I used this regex

`(?!").*(?=(" =))`

This is working when I tried it in [RegExr](http://www.regexr.com/) and in this [online tool](http://www.online-utility.org/text/grep.jsp). But in my OSX Terminal it does not work, the output is empty

`grep -o '(?!").*(?=(" =))' input.txt`

What is wrong here? Do I have to escape some characters? I try everyone and nothing changes.

Thank you so much and please excuse my lack of knowledge about this topic.

Comment: Have you tried `grep -Po '...' input.txt`? It works to me, but I don't know if it does in OSX.

Comment: when I saw `osx` tag, I knew the sed/grep .. won't be same as gnu ones. but I don't think the grep by default support PCRE.

Comment: Yes, @fedorqui, and the response of the Terminal is the help of the grep command :\

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lookaheads and lookbehinds are PCRE features so you have to use the parameter `-P`:

```
grep -Po '(?!").*(?=(" =))' input.txt
```

Comment: It seems that I don't have the PCRE headers installed as this answer points http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19541066/how-to-install-pcre-development-headers-on-mac-osx

Comment: You can also "simplify" it to ``grep -Po '"\K.*(?=(" =))' input.txt``

Comment: also, I have noticed a tiny problem with your regex. I wrote another answer to explain it.

Comment: @Aleks-DanielJakimenko I just copied his regex. +1 for your eagle eyes.

Answer (score 1):

This should do:

```
awk -F\" '{print $2}' file
```

It uses `"` as separators, and then print second field.

Answer (score 1):

[steffen`s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25623063/2698019) is right, you have to use `-P` flag. But there is also a problem with your regex.

Imagine this input:
`"an arbitrary string" = " =this is the text one"`

Your regex will fail dramatically.
To solve this you have to use something like this:

`grep -Po '^"\K.*?(?=(" =))'`

- `^` to prevent other matches that do not begin from the line start.
- `\K` is just easier to read. (It also allows you to match strings with arbitrary length)
- `.*?` to make it non-greedy.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer but I use your regex in regexr.com with the example of my question and it does not work :\

Comment: @emenegro yes. I suppose that regexr.com is using javascript built-in regex engine, which does not support ``\K``. Indeed, a lot of regex features are working exclusively in perl, but ``\K`` works in ``grep`` too! It is up to you, you can use ``(?!^")`` instead of ``^"\K``, but both should work in ``grep -P``.