# How do I build for GHC 7.10.2 in the container-based infrastructure?

Tags: haskell, ghc, travis-ci

I have a project that requires GHC 7.10.2, so to use Travis CI I must install the required version of GHC myself in a pre-install step.

I currently have this working with

```
env:
 - CABALVER=1.22 GHCVER=7.10.2

before_install:
 - |
    travis_retry sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:hvr/ghc
    travis_retry sudo apt-get update
    travis_retry sudo apt-get install cabal-install-$CABALVER ghc-$GHCVER
    export PATH=/opt/ghc/$GHCVER/bin:/opt/cabal/$CABALVER/bin:$PATH
```

in my `.travis.yml`; but am limited to using the "legacy" infrastructure because of my use of `sudo`.

I'd like to take advantage of the new container-based infrastructure, and have followed the [migration docs](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/migrating-from-legacy/?utm_source=legacy-notice&utm_medium=banner&utm_campaign=legacy-upgrade) as far as I can, resulting in

```
sudo: false

env:
 - CABALVER=1.22 GHCVER=7.10.2

addons:
  apt:
    sources:
    - hvr-ghc
    packages:
    - cabal-install-$CABALVER
    - ghc-$GHCVER

before_install:
 - |
    export PATH=/opt/ghc/$GHCVER/bin:/opt/cabal/$CABALVER/bin:$PATH
```

as what seems to me should be the equivalent of the above. But this proceeds to use the default (7.4) version of GHC, which results in a failed build.

How do I build for Haskell 7.10.2 in the container-based infrastructure? Specifically, what should I have in my `.travis.yml`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an explanation of how to do this with Stack in the guide, you can see a full example at:

https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/blob/master/doc/GUIDE.md#travis-with-caching

Comment: That approach (which I'll try next; just asking ahead now) looks like it would require me to build the whole Haskell stack manually. I'm not sure I know how to do that.

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius It will just fetch all the packages you need from `stackage`. Installing `stack` is painless if you follow the tutorial. I would say this is the best approach specially in the container-base infrastructure because you will get caching for free. I have tried it and it works like a charm.

Comment: Is what's there in the example sufficient to build a full 7.10.2 stack, or do I need more? (Again, I'll check when I have access; just looking ahead.)

Comment: The example handles everything you need for the full tool chain

Comment: That fails [pretty spectacularly](https://travis-ci.org/orome/crypto-enigma/builds/82636563). What am I missing?

Comment: I have no idea, you haven't told us anything that explains why it's failing. There are many examples in the wild of it succeeding (e.g., the yaml repo).

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius You need to have a `stack.yaml` file for your project.  The command is failing because you are missing this file.  The clue is this output from your Travis build: `Run from outside a project, using implicit global config`

Comment: Was that always a link to the Travis output? If so, I missed it first time around. I could have sworn it was plain text.

Comment: Ah. No idea about `stack`. Never used it. What would that look like for `7.10.2`?

Comment: The page I linked to is the user's guide for Stack. The top of the page gives instructions on getting started. But tldr use stack init like the error message says

Comment: I see — so I need to use Stack locally too. I don't yet. Will I encounter any issues with my local Haskell/GHC config if I install it and used it for this? Does installing it locally for (just) this purpose have side effects?

Comment: No. And you don't need to use it locally. You just need a stack.yaml file.

Comment: Cool. Works now (I'll make sure it continues to for a bit). I had to dig around to get [`pcre.h`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27819983/656912), whatever that is, and install bunch of packages along with Stack, but so far so good. How do I confirm thought that it's doing what I expect? It no longer prints a GHC version to the log — where in `.travis.yml` should I add `ghc --version`?

Comment: stack exec -- git --version. At this point, I'd recommend reading through the guide, it will cover most of these kinds of questions

Comment: Now it fails. I've made no code changes at all, just changes to the one or two changes to a readme file, but [now my Travis builds fail](https://travis-ci.org/orome/crypto-enigma/jobs/82974788) with "No compiler found, expected minor version match with ghc-7.10.2 (x86_64) (based on resolver setting in /home/travis/build/orome/crypto-enigma/stack.yaml). Try running stack setup to locally install the correct GHC"

Comment: That's because you're trying to use `ghc` before installing it. You just got lucky with the cache hit in the first few runs most likely. Use `--install-ghc` on the `stack ghc` call. Also, this is really getting too long for an SO comments section...

Comment: This is [now tripping me up](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33437022/656912) (I think) when I try to use automatic deployment to Hackage.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you are using `language: haskell`. Could you try with `language: c`.

My understanding is that travis does not really support `ghc-7.10.x` just yet (there are outstanding issues). The workaround is to bypass and install it manually (using the `hvr-ghc` ppa); hence the `language: c` instead of haskell.

Another tip. Start by removing `env`. I am pretty sure it won't work inside your `addons`. Simply use `ghc-7.10.2` and `cabal-1.22`. Now your`addons`should work fine. Check your travis log to be sure.

I can confirm the stack tutorial (link by Michael Snoyman) is quite good. But it should work with or without stack.

For reference here is a travis file where I try to minimize the usage of `sudo` to the strict minimum:

https://github.com/PierreR/language-puppet/blob/450ca249e23300351085d24fd58dcf9f429769d5/.travis.yml

As you see, I still use the old travis infra because I need Ruby2.x with the C header.

Here is kind of the same travis file but without using stack (stack is only useful with caching):

https://github.com/bartavelle/language-puppet/blob/master/.travis.yml

Comment: Any ideas on how to get this to work without Stack? [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32830882/656912) assumes Stack, which I don't use.

Comment: I said explicitly it should work with or without stash. It doesn't ?

Comment: By using `language: c` there will be no default `ghc` so at least you should see that you are now using the expected ghc-7.10.x.

Comment: I just get `"./configure && make && make test" exited with 127`.

Comment: Ok I might know of one problem. Could you replace ` - ghc-$GHCVER` with  `ghc-7.10.2` in `addons` ? Don't use `env` for now, you have only one version anyhow.