# How do I automatically deploy from Travis CI with the container-based infrastructure?

Tags: deployment, travis-ci

When I use the [Travis CI](https://travis-ci.org) ["container-based" infrastructure](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/workers/container-based-infrastructure/), I must have

```
sudo: false
```

set in [my `.travis.yml`](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/5033#issuecomment-152530176); but this appears to be incompatible with [automatic deployment](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/) using, for example

```
deploy:
  provider: hackage
```

which causes my build to fail with

> Installing deploy dependencies
>   sudo: must be setuid root

How can I use automatic deployment from Travis CI with the container-based infrastructure?

---

The final lines of the build log, starting with successful completion of the code build and test are:

```
The command "stack $ARGS --no-terminal --install-ghc test --haddock" exited with 0.
#cache.2
store build cache
83.58schanges detected, packing new archive
.
#...
.
uploading archive
#dpl.0
Fetching: dpl-1.8.7.gem (100%)
Successfully installed dpl-1.8.7
1 gem installed
#dpl.1
Installing deploy dependencies
sudo: must be setuid root
#dpl.2
Preparing deploy
No stash found.
cabal check failed
failed to deploy
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't possible with the  Travis CI "container-based" infrastructure, [because](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/5033#issuecomment-152545073) Hackage depends on `cabal`, which requires `sudo`.

Comment: How so? Could you ellaborate?